# How to Play audio files by specifying Start and end in Corona or iOS & Android?

Tags: android, ios, audio, coronasdk

**Scenario:** I have a Long file - Say 30 Minutes. I want to play the file in interval 7-10 minutes.

[how to play a mp3 file from the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091570/how-to-play-a-mp3-file-from-the-middle)

[C# play MP3 file from specified time for the specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664469/c-play-mp3-file-from-specified-time-for-the-specified-time)

The above questions seem to be similar but they are for Desktop Apps. I am not sure if they can be used in iOS & Android or Corona.

**Detail:**

I would be really thankful if someone could tell me how to play a part
of a sound file, for then it would be possible to do the cuts in a
virtual manner. If i could say something to the effect

`media.load( 'sound.mp3', start = 5.43, stop = 9.75 )`

then i'd be able to skip cutting of separate sound files in a wave editor. Maybe there is already a way to do something similar? I couldn't find anything in the docs. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:**

Found a pyglet project for the same.
http://code.google.com/p/suimm/

Comment: @nik countdown timer? No idea abt that? any sample code or implementations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use audio.play() with the 'duration' parameter and audio.seek() to set the starting position.